# Merging objects and functions inside classes

Tags: typescript

I am trying to merge a function and an object inside a class.

Code below is my unsuccessful attempt at creating such functionality only shown to illustrate the desired outcome.

```
type Algorithm = string;

class Computer {
    constructor(private specialData: number[]) { }
    compute(data: number[], algorithm: Algorithm): number[] {
        switch(algorithm) {
            case 'algorithm1':
                return this.compute.algorithm1(data);
            case 'algorithm2':
                return this.compute.algorithm2(data);
        }
        throw new Error('Unknown algorithm');
    }
    compute = {
        algorithm1: (data: number[]): number[] => {
            return add(data, this.specialData);
        },
        algorithm2: (data: number[]): number[] => {
            return multiply(data, this.specialData);
        }
    }
}
```

The usage of such class would be:

```
const c = new Computer();

const data = [2, 8, 7, 5];

c.compute(data, 'algorithm1');
// or
c.compute.algorithm1(data);
```

The reason I can't just place the functions inside a `namespace Computer` is because I need the value of `this`(class Computer) to use for calculation.

Is there any way to achieve such result?

Comment: You cannot use the same name for a method and property. You have to rename the `compute` method or `compute` property for this code to work.

Comment: So you want to implement the `add` and `multiple` methods in the `Computer` class?

Comment: @MaartenDev `add` and `multiple` are just some outside functions used for calculating.

Comment: So what is your problem then?

Comment: @MaartenDev In pure javascript you can combine functions with objects even inside "classes", I am asking how to do it inside typescript.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WGkE2W) meet your needs?  Some of the typing is a little annoying to get right (I gave up and wrote `this as any` inside an implementation under the assumption that your implementation will be correct; to do otherwise would probably require some external wrapper function).  If so, I can write up an answer; if not, please [edit] the example to show failing use cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would look something like this:

```
class Computer {
    constructor(private specialData: number[]) { }

    compute = Object.assign(
        (data: number[], algorithm: keyof this["compute"]): number[] =>
            (this as any).compute[algorithm](data),
        {
            algorithm1: (data: number[]): number[] => {
                console.log(this.specialData);
                return null!; // impl here
            },
            algorithm2: (data: number[]): number[] => {
                console.log(this.specialData);
                return null!; // impl here
            }
        }
    );
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot create a method named `compute` and a property named `compute` in the same class.  You have to pick one.  I've chosen to make it an instance property of a function type, which also has individual properties.

You can verify that it works as expected:

```
const c = new Computer([1, 2, 3]);
const data = [2, 8, 7, 5];
c.compute(data, 'algorithm1');
c.compute.algorithm1(data);
```

---

The typing is a little odd because of the somewhat circular dependencies; when you call `compute()` as a *function*, the acceptable values for the second argument depend on the individual *properties*.  It would be nice for the compiler to just know about them, so if you add `algorithm3` as a property, the compiler would automatically understand that you can call `compute([], "algorithm3")`.  This works by giving the parameter the type `keyof this["compute"]`.  Inside the implementation of `compute` the function, I used a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to write `this as any` so the compiler doesn't complain about how the type of `compute` depends on itself in a circular way.  In fact, lots of seemingly innocuous changes might result in a circular dependency error.

If you want to make the typing more robust, you might be forced to manually annotate things and refactor a bit.  Possibly like this:

```
type Algorithm = "algorithm1" | "algorithm2";

type Compute =
    Record<Algorithm, (data: number[]) => number[]> &
    ((data: number[], algorithm: Algorithm) => number[]);

class Computer {

    compute: Compute;

    constructor(private specialData: number[]) {
        const compute: Compute = (data, algorithm) => this.compute[algorithm](data);
        compute.algorithm1 = data => {
            console.log(this.specialData);
            return data;
        }
        compute.algorithm2 = data => {
            console.log(this.specialData);
            return data;
        }
        this.compute = compute;
    }

}
```

---

Note that in both cases, the `Algorithm` type of `algorithm` is narrower than `string`; it's specifically the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of acceptable string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html) corresponding to actual algorithms.  Assuming that all calls to `compute()` are written in TypeScript, that means you don't need to have a runtime check to make sure `algorithm` is one of these allowed values.  The compiler will enforce it for you:

```
c.compute(data, 'oops'); // compiler error!
// Argument of type '"oops"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Algorithm'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPksUvBiFFEgMID2YMArgC4QBOeRJ38twUzNo3jNabABQw2ASwBuIVklgR40zABEFIAFxJgjMACN2AbQC6ASjxIAvoW496TRQF4kAeUMArFcwB0FFDSAObA4lwODuIAJlq6+kamZgA0SJjBYtLMABZgugDWEACetABmSDnSUCYARLwMLBA1lvEGxmzmSC4AfBGR-eKVVBRpwEUWfvXOECbpmTlgZjFaFsl9-ZwbG3MyCwCMusvMOnptSRatiR1mXd2bWw+8-LQYEH4YtMGD2VV+yqoaFYAbnWDwcbAgzEYbGASFixxBYIcNjWSO4OyyuQATId4ScEu1zBdTldOj17miHE8oC83h8vkM-jAVGoMJpjhZEZTwZDobC8VzKXYkcL+py+nY+tTmKQunoIAB3GhORoSEx7VJY1IAZksgtIfAEcK0cpMWqQAA5UgB2VIAVjM+vgkxVrCOIFSAHIMftPeKeC6GqwAhgMrtcnt3eL8JLQJBYAhkGhMFgsZw+swisykABBUPzXJymo+iM1JAAHyQxfz4bAWJq+ozWeQdCDyBcoOIACUVGJogAePNhzFgVLuy6Eyy3EmTu4AMk7SHE45nSVSJbyuZrI6s5IJ5xBUvIlGVbY4BEXU0aulb00PG2lQhEYkkMnkin+rPZ+LO1ysBCRaUDTbG9XXbJc8XXbcFl3O5GSvVhZmg3Iljxf0wQQt4Nz2OU8WnADuWpWl3k+b5fk-QEOX1JEIShGFjQRRduFFR4wJDYcFjTNw8PJAjKSI14SIZH4oCZFlKJAdDKVovkGJAaj+hYrZ4LAuVMIU4hJWY+wSCA+A5WARVT2mNUNSQc1dSkg1+BlHikDNVIrSQW0kAdJ1A2md0vWwv13Mw9iCzASM0MPKUPMaLykE9WhaBgKBfKQAB6RLgJgaRXg4dg2DEABCPpktzNhggMCBgBlMoKmbKKahiuKak9JAqj0WgZUCEJQEMV4KloJA4DYcBIXYJAKszbNPSHQLPT8JAYyAA)